# print two dimensional string column wise

Tags: arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have two dimensional String array. Each cell can have different string size. i want to print it column wise. I have tried :

```
public void printArr(String[][] arr) {
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {

        for(int j=1;j<arr[i].length;j++)
        {  
            System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

But it is printing the array row-wise. Any help will be appreciated.
Array Structure : It has fixed number of rows but each row can have different column length.

Comment: if i==j you can directly print arr[j][i] inside that loop of yours.
otherwise, you got it i suppose :)

Comment: Nope.. i!=j. It will generate arrayindexoutofbounds exception.

Comment: No.. the no of rows is 4 but each row can have different length columns :P

Comment: if that's the case, how will you be able to print columnwise? because for some i,j there will be values missing?

Comment: Exactly! That is the complexity. I am not able to solve it. :(

Comment: it's not hard to solve it, but i am unable to understand your use case. suppose an i,j value does not exists, what do you want to print in that scenario?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8r2Vnj88GeLWJadkZYbTQ1RXc/view Kindly see this link. It shows how the elements are stored in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i understand:

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    {
        if (max < arr[k].length)
        {
            max = arr[k].length;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if (i >= arr[j].length)
            {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(arr[j][i] + " ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: It is giving arrayindexoutofbounds exception. Because every row can have different column length. By mistake, I wrote in comment that column is M. I have added details about the array structure. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope its helpful.

```
    public void printArr(String[][] arr) {
    int row = arr.length;
    int column = arr[0].length;

    for(int i=0;i<column;i++) {

    for(int j=1;j<row;j++)
    {  
        System.out.println(arr[j][i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Each row has different length columns. so the above code is giving ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception